# titanium offline app

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, desktop, titanium

I am developing an app that should work offline on a desktop or mobile. At the end of the day, I need to sync it up with a central data base (a rails app). It needs to store a few tables and sync from the central database. Is titanium a good solution for me?

-Sri

Answer (score 0):

I'd say Yes, consider Wunderlist (I'm not affiliated with these guys btw, but I use that app every day), it features cloud storage, desktop and mobile (and web).  They don't release details of their back-end, but that doesn't really matter and it's their right (my guess is that they use node.js+couch though).  I'm not close to Rails, but I can tell you that Titanium talks JSON natively, and I guess Rails does too, or at least via a plugin.

Wouldn't recommend it for a 3d shooter perhaps, but sounds good for your needs (and it's easy and free to try if you already know javascript)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advise. Will check it now. Yes Rails can talk with JSON through Activesupport gem.